Inconsistency between ros2 topic hz and bw
I have run into some unexpected behavior reflected in the outputs of ros2 topic hz and ros2 topic bw.
Context:
I am building a ros2_control hardware interface that runs on a realtime kernel Raspberry Pi 4 and controls several actuators over CAN. Each actuator has an exported state interface that gets published through the default a joint_state_broadcaster into a /joint_states topic.
Tests:
I am trying to find the limits of the controller manager update rate and topic publishing rate. With 2 actuators connected, I ran some tests at update rates of 400hz, 600hz, 800hz, and 1khz, and in a separate terminal ran ros2 topic hz /joint_states and ros2 topic bw /joint_states.
At 400hz, 600hz, and 800hz controller manager update rates, I got the following topic publishing frequencies and bandwidths:

~400hz @ 46kbps
~600hz @ 70kbps
~795hz @ 93kbps

These present a linear relationship between topic frequency and bandwidth (as expected, since it is theoretically transmitting a constant amount of data per loop).
Issue:
When I ran the controller manager at 1khz, I got a topic frequency of ~750hz @ 115kbps, which is inconsistent with the relationship I saw previously. 115kbps is consistent the slower rates in terms of bandwidth per control loop rate, but the topic publishing frequency was not keeping up with the control loop rate.
I figure that at 1khz, I am nearing the limit of the Pi4 cpu, but I am confused how the bandwidth increased while the topic frequency decreased. It seems to indicate that the data transmission per loop changed, but I don't know how that would be possible.
If anyone could shed some light on why this might be happening, or if my understanding of hz and bw is incorrect, I would be very appreciative!

In my past experience with ROS2, ros2 topic hz cannot accurately measure high-frequency topic rates. You can perform testing by manually subscribing to the topic (be sure to modify the QoS queue length to a larger value).

Thank you for your quick reply! I will try to measure the topic frequency myself through a subscription and see if it results in a frequency consistent with the bandwidth.

I recorded loop timings through both logger printouts and ros2bag timestamps and you were right! The application was running and publishing at 1kHz but ros2 topic hz was underreporting the frequency.
